# MySQL MVC application on visual studio 2013 using wizard

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I tried creating a sample MVC application using the visual studio plugin for MySQL. The sample runs OK but when I tried to add a controller by right clicking on the controller folder(solution explorer) and selecting Add, I do not see the controller option. I tried searching for that option (templates on the internet) but to no avail.
 But when I try to create a simple ASP.net MVC application without the MySQL wizard for visual studio 2013, I am able to see the Add--> Controller option.
Note However that I can add a controller manually by simply adding a class and typing in the contents of the controller and then creating the view when I use the MySQL wizard.
**EDIT:**I realized that it is not such a big problem after all. I was able to copy other controller classes and create my own controller class. After all a controller is a class. I had to however create a View folder which the visual studio wizard would have created for me.